# EF 4.0 change n_varchar to varchar in ouput sql

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4.0, is there a way to change the sql that's generated by the entity framework from n_varchar to varchar?   Thanks.

Comment: are you looking to something like changing type of the property column - e.g. `[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]public string UserName { get; set; }`

Comment: Do i put this on the self-tracking entities? Is the column attribute included with EF 4.0?

Comment: why is it that it's coming out as nvarchar(4000)..slows the query i am running if i manually change that to varchar(4000) the query runs on the spot..But still dont know the correct way to make EF generate the varchar instead of nvarchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, I cant find the Column Attribute.  What assembly do i need to include? I am using EF 4.0